# I am trying to update an SQLIte table from another table and my Syntax seems to be wrong

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I created a databasehelper contract file so my SQLite Syntax is different from all the examples i have seen thus far, and i dont seem to to getting it right. i would appreciate some guidance on the correct syntax to be used

My code is below;+

String updt = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME4 + " " +

```
        "SET "
        + COLUMN_TAKEAWAY_PK_COST   = ("SELECT  " +COLUMN_PACK_COST+" " +
        "FROM " + TABLE_NAME6+"" +
        " WHERE " +COLUMN_PACK_TYPE+" = " +COLUMN_TAKEAWAY_PK_TYPE+" " +
        " WHERE "
                 EXIST
                        "SELECT *
                        "FROM " + TABLE_NAME6+"" +
                        " WHERE " +COLUMN_PACK_TYPE+" = " +COLUMN_TAKEAWAY_PK_TYPE+""

                );
```

Comment: You have WHERE .... WHERE.  you probably want AND or OR instead of the 2nd WHERE (which is syntactically incorrect). You should use **EXISTS** not EXIST and the SELECT clause for the EXISTS should be enclosed in parenthesises **(** and **)**.

Comment: Ok I will make the changes .. thanks

Comment: I finally got it working. thanks for your help

Comment: String updatePack = "UPDATE FP_Master SET TakeAwayPkCost = (SELECT Pack_Cost FROM Take_Away_Pack_Details WHERE Pack_Type = TakeAwayPkType)";
        db.execSQL(updatePack);

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

The first is that you have two WHERE clauses when you can only have one (although there can be a where clause within a subquery). WHERE expects a result of true or false (1 or greater or 0) from an expression, you can use AND or OR to get a result of true or false from two results so you should be using

```
 WHERE result_of_expression AND result_of_the_other_expression
```

or 
     WHERE result_of_expression AND result_of_the_other_expression

The second issue is that you then try to use a subquery. A subquery needs to be enclosed in parenthesises **(** at the start and **)** at the end.

The third issue is that **EXIST** is not a keyword it is **EXISTS**.

- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

So the above could be :-

```
String updt = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME4 + 
    " SET " + COLUMN_TAKEAWAY_PK_COST + " = ( " +  //<<<<<<<<<< OPEN PARENTHESIS FOR SUBQUERY
    " SELECT  " + COLUMN_PACK_COST +
    " FROM " + TABLE_NAME6 +
    " WHERE " +COLUMN_PACK_TYPE+" = " + COLUMN_TAKEAWAY_PK_TYPE +
    " AND EXISTS " + //<<<<<<<<<< AND INSTEAD OF WHERE and EXISTS INSTEAD OF EXISTS
    "(" + //<<<<<<<<<< OPEN PARENTHESIS FOR SUB-SUBQUERY
    " SELECT * " +
    " FROM " + TABLE_NAME6 +
    " WHERE " + COLUMN_PACK_TYPE + " = " + COLUMN_TAKEAWAY_PK_TYPE + 
    " ) " + //<<<<<<<<<< CLOSE PARENTHESIS FOR SUB-SUBQUERY
    ")" //<<<<<<<<<<< CLOSE PARENTHESIS FOR SUBQUERY
    );
```

- Note the above is in-principle code

  - it doesn't necessarily reflect the results you want as this cannot be determined
  - rather it attempts to clarify the syntax that could be used
  - it has not bee tested so it may contain errors

---

As per your comment you wanted a less complex query as per :-

```
String updatePack = "UPDATE FP_Master SET TakeAwayPkCost = (SELECT Pack_Cost FROM Take_Away_Pack_Details WHERE Pack_Type = TakeAwayPkType)";
```